# Update UI from another window BackgroundWorker vb.net WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, backgroundworker, ui-thread, begininvoke

I am working on a wpf project...I've faced similar issues in the past,but didn't get the answer to it and that's why i'm asking again :)

My WPF app has 2 windows,one works as a splash screen and the 2nd one is just a basic window with a canvas.The splash screen has a `BackGroundWorker`.Now,i have this code :

```
  Dim h2 as new Window2
  For Each fi As FileInfo In New DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath + 
  "\data\img\em_sml").GetFiles()

  h2.canvas.children.add(new Button)
```

Now, my question is how do i use this code in the `backgroundworker` in Window1 ?? I  tried this :

```
 Dim method as Delegate
 Private Sub BgWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BgWorker.DoWork

 If h2.Dispatcher.CheckAccess Then      
  For Each fi As FileInfo In New DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath + 
  "\data\img\em_sml").GetFiles()
  h2.canvas.children.add(new Button)

 Else

  h2.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, method)
  For Each fi As FileInfo In New DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath + 
  "\data\img\em_sml").GetFiles()

  h2.canvas.children.add(new Button)

 End if
```

A few things i'ld like to clear here :

• I got the sample code from another SO post(i converted it from c#)

• `Dim method as Delegate`,i don't really know how to use a delegate function

• The code above returns some exceptions like `Parameter name:Method , Value can not be null`(I know what this means but as i said,i don't know how i can use the delegate function in such a case)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you're using is trying to invoke to the UI thread via `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`. This is the way to do it in threads, but not in a `BackgroundWorker`. In a BGW you're supposed to call the [**`ReportProgress()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t(v=vs.110).aspx) combined with subscribing to the [**`ProgressChanged` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

However for what you're trying to do, this is not good at all...

**For starters:** You should **NEVER** create controls in a background thread! All work related to the UI (User Interface) must always, *always*, **always** be done on the UI thread **ONLY**.

**Secondly:** There isn't really a good reason for trying to do this in a background thread. The way you're doing it now constantly updates the UI thread, causing it to lag/freeze anyway. What you *could* do to minimize the lag is to add the buttons in batches, but then as I said before you shouldn't be creating controls in a background thread at all.

**Finally:** The whole operation of iterating a few files and creating buttons for them really isn't very heavy. Unless you have thousands of files (in which case you should only ***display*** them in batches) this will not take that long to perform on the UI thread.

**Conclusion:** Skip the `BackgroundWorker` and run your code on the UI thread instead. If you have a really huge amount of files to load, store their paths in a list, only load them in batches and let the user decide when to load the next batch of files.